# Another way to calculate the integral $ \int_{0}^{1} (x-x^{2})^{3/2} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof, substitution

$$\int_{0}^{1} (x-x^{2})^{3/2} dx=\dfrac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1}[1-(2x-1)^{2}]^{3/2}dx=\dfrac{1}{8}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{cos^{4}\theta}{2}d\theta=\dfrac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos^{4}d\theta=\dfrac{1}{8}(\dfrac{3\pi}{16})=\dfrac{3\pi}{128}$$
The change of variable $2x-1 = sin\theta$ was made.

How could it be integrated without the "trick" $(x-x^{2})^{3/2}=\dfrac{1}{8}[1-(2x-1)^{2}]^{3/2}$?

Comment: It isn't really a "trick". Completing the square is very helpful in many cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also the following way.

Let $x=\cos^2t$, where $t\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Thus, $$\int\limits_0^1(x-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\sin^3t\cos^3t(-2\sin{t}\cos{t})dt=2\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4t\cos^4tdt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^42tdt=\frac{1}{32}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\cos4t)^2dt=\frac{1}{32}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-2\cos4t+\frac{1+\cos8t}{2}\right)dt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{32}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi}{128}.$$

Answer (score 4):

See this, 
$$\int x^{3/2} (1-x)^{3/2} dx$$
$$=B(5/2,5/2)=\frac{3 \pi}{128}$$

$B(x,y)$ is Beta function.

Comment: Of course, but a big $\beta$ is wrote by the different way.

Comment: But how is it calculated by hand $ B(5/2,5/2) $?

Comment: @edwards, $B(m,n)=\frac{\Gamma{m}\Gamma{n}}{\Gamma{(m+n)}}$